# Speeding up iterating a List<> with foreach loop, involving database operations at each iteration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, loops, foreach

In the application I am working, each user has a submission. For each submission, I need to create a group of users (`PeerGroup`) based on the given size (`groupSize`). For example, for each submission, a `PeerGroup` of 3 students can be created. The size of `submissions` may scale up to 1000.

I have the following to iterate through the `submissions` list. Inside each loop, I order the users in an ascending order based on the number of memberships to the groups (`PeerGroupMemberships`). If a user is assigned to more submissions, then they should be on the bottom, and should not be selected. Then I use `Take` to retain those users. This way I try to keep a balance.

```
 List<Submission> submissions = _context.Submissions.Where(s => s.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId).ToList();

 foreach (Submission submission in submissions)
 {
     if (submission.PeerGroup == null)
     {
         PeerGroup peerGroup = new PeerGroup { SubmissionId = submission.Id};
         _context.PeerGroups.Add(peerGroup);
         _context.SaveChanges();

         IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDto> peers =
             _context.ApplicationUsers
                     .Where(s => s.Submissions.Select(ce => ce.ReviewRoundId).Contains(reviewRoundId))
                     .Where(s => s.Id != submission.StudentId)   
                     .OrderBy(m => m.PeerGroupMemberships.Count(pg => pg.PeerGroup.Submission.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId))
                     .Select(m => new ApplicationUserDto
                     {
                         FullName = m.FullName,
                         Id = new Guid(m.Id),
                         ProfilePhoto = m.ProfilePhoto,
                         NumberOfPeersToReview = m.PeerGroupMemberships.Count(pg => pg.PeerGroup.Submission.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoun
                     }).Take(groupSize);


         foreach (ApplicationUserDto p in peers)
         {
             PeerGroupMembership groupMembership = new PeerGroupMembership { UserId = p.Id.ToString(), PeerGroupId = peerGroup.Id  };
             _context.PeerGroupMemberships.Add(groupMembership);
             _context.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
 }
```

The code works fine, but each loop takes almost 5 seconds, which can lead to a very long delay with 1000 submissions to loop through.

I wonder if this is normal or if the code somehow can be improved. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try calling `SaveChanges()` *after* you add all of the Peer Group Memberships to the context.

Comment: If that works out, try one über `SaveChanges()` for the whole thing.

Comment: `.Where(s => s.Submissions.Any(ce => ce.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId))` should be faster than `.Where(s => s.Submissions.Select(ce => ce.ReviewRoundId).Contains(reviewRoundId))`

Comment: You don't need to select the entire `ApplicationUserDto` object as you're only using the `Id`. If `ProfilePhoto` is actually an image or a `byte[]` then sparing yourself selecting it over and over might help. Have you tried running it through a [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) to get an idea of what the hot path is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things: First it doesn't look like you are leveraging EF to map relationships between entities. For general bulk update scenarios, what you are doing by assigning FKs to entities and saving is typically more efficient, but for inserts it is more costly when you are relying on the database to assign PKs that you need to retrieve to set FKs.

At a minimum because you are inserting a PeerGroup and a PeerGroupMembership, you should map the relationship between these two entities so that you can create the PeerGroup, then associate it to the new Membership and allow EF to work out the FKs when you perform the single SaveChanges call.

For instance, your code can be sped up considerably like so:

```
var submissions = _context.Submissions
    .Where(s => s.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId && s.PeerGroup == null)
    .Select(s => {Submissionid = s.Id, s.SudentId).ToList();

foreach(var submission in submissions)
{
    var peerGroup = new PeerGroup{ SubmissionId = s.SubmissionId };
    _context.PeerGroups.Add(peerGroup);

    var unassignedUserIds = _context.ApplicationUsers
        .Where(u => u.Submissions.Any(s => s.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId
            && u.Id != submission.StudentId)
        .OrderBy(u => u.PeerGroupMemberships.Count(pg => pg.PeerGroup.Submission.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId))
        .Select(u => Id)
        .Take(groupSize);

    foreach(var userId in unassignedUserIds)
    {
        var groupMembership = new PeerGroupMembership { UserId = userId.ToString(), PeerGroup = peerGroup };
        _context.PeerGroupMemberships.Add(groupMemberShip);
    }
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

The key points here:  When selecting the submissions, you only need the Submission ID and the Student ID. We can also eliminate all submissions that have a peer group already. No need to pull the rest.  When pulling the Peers we can use `.Any` to find ones with the ReviewRound, and we only need to select the User ID.  With a relationship mapped between PeerGroup and PeerGroupMembership we can create our PeerGroupMembership entity and assign it's PeerGroup to the new entity we created above. When `SaveChanges()` gets called it will insert the set of entities ensuring the PeerGroups are inserted first and the FK's mapped correctly when the Memberships get saved.  A side note, why is the UserId in PeerGroupMembership a string? This looks like it could be a FK back to the ApplicationUser, so it should match the data type.

For tuning performance aim to only load as much data as you need and nothing else. This applies to columns read, and # of rows read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, appreciated :)